# Importing code from github to Android Studio errors

Tags: android-studio

So I tried to import code from a github repository into Android Studio. I used VCS and everything went fine, no errors at all. But when I went to MainActivity.java it says cannot resolve symbol 'R' in this line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
I already checked the xml files and found no errors, as well as ran gradle cleans and builds. That didn't do it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Clean and Build the project .

Answer (score 0):

So as you are saying, cleaning and rebuilding didn't help it. You might want to maybe upgrade/downgrade your gradle build version or try to copy it in again, since sometimes when copying errors occur for no outer reason.